# POST value exists in raw post data, but not on php $_POST

Tags: php, ajax, post

So my raw post data looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXQrRmAvDBGudXqzO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmd"

update_cars_item
------WebKitFormBoundaryXQrRmAvDBGudXqzO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="john_id"

30
------WebKitFormBoundaryXQrRmAvDBGudXqzO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="item_id"


------WebKitFormBoundaryXQrRmAvDBGudXqzO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_make_id"
Allard
```

But if I do a `print_r($_POST)` on php the `model_make_id` value `is empty`, anyone had problems like this?

Comment: Can we see more code? The form that generates `POST` data for instance as well as the code that processes it.

Comment: I have had this before, if you pass the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` through with the post request the data should appear within `$_POST`

Comment: @MattBurrow: With `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you will only get garbage, because this obviously _is_  a `multipart/form-data` request … and has to be indicated as such, otherwise PHP won’t know what to do with it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that at some point in your code you have something like this:

if ($_POST['model_make_id'] = "")....

Using a single = instead a double == overwrites the value in $_POST['model_make_id'] and from that point the value is empty.

You can do a search in your code or write echo $_POST['model_make_id'] from the begining of your code and moving this echo through your code until you find the point that it changes its value.